# How to convert a log file to JSON format using shell script?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, fluentd

I have three lines of syslog, I need to convert this data to JSON in order to forward it to elasticsearch using fluentd. Is there an internal way to do this or do we have to convert the log and then forward.

Sample Log

```
Feb  3 17:26:36 servername augenrules: failure 1
Feb  3 17:26:38 servername NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1580768798.0902] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file"}
Feb  3 17:26:44 servername Unit metricbeat.service entered failed state
Feb  3 18:01:44 servername rtprocess[4815]: (RTI rtscantask[6106]@xx)#app#ClsRtdb_query_attr.cpp#931#ClsRtdbAttrTbl::fetchScalarVal(): Failed to fetch scalar value because failed to convert address to number address.
Feb  3 19:26:36 servername augenrules: failure 1
Feb  3 19:45:38 servername NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1580768798.0902] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Feb  3 20:26:44 servername Unit metricbeat.service entered failed state.
Feb  3 21:01:44 servername rtprocess[4815]: (RTI rtscantask[6106]@xx)#app#ClsRtdb_query_attr.cpp#931#ClsRtdbAttrTbl::fetchScalarVal(): Failed to fetch scalar value because failed to convert address to number address.
```

Required output

```
{"date":"Feb  3 17:26:36","server":"servername","error":"augenrules: failure 1"}
{"date":"Feb  3 17:26:38","server":"servername","error":"NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1580768798.0902] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file"}
{"date":"Feb  3 17:26:44","server":"servername","error":"Unit metricbeat.service entered failed state."}
{"date":"Feb  3 18:01:44","server":"servername","error":"rtprocess[4815]: (RTI rtscantask[6106]@servername)#app#ClsRtdb_query_attr.cpp#931#ClsRtdbAttrTbl::fetchScalarVal(): Failed to fetch scalar value because failed to convert address to number address."}
{"date":"Feb  3 19:26:36","server":"servername","error":"augenrules: failure 1"}
{"date":"Feb  3 19:45:38","server":"servername","error":"NetworkManager[830]: <info>  [1580768798.0902] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state fileservername
{"date":"Feb  3 20:26:44","server":"atlswdo087","error":"Unit metricbeat.service entered failed state."}
{"date":"Feb  3 21:01:44","server":"servername","error":"rtprocess[4815]: (RTI rtscantask[6106]@servername)#app#ClsRtdb_query_attr.cpp#931#ClsRtdbAttrTbl::fetchScalarVal(): Failed to fetch scalar value because failed to convert address to number address."}
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is the Solution I have come up with we can use the same in a while loop to convert the whole log to Json :D 

Feb  3 17:26:36 servername augenrules: failure 1

dt=$(echo $line | awk '{print ($1" "$2" " $3)}')
ser_nm=$(echo $line | awk '{print ($4)}')
error_msg=$(echo $line | awk '{print ($5$6$7$8$9$10)}')
echo {\"date\":\"$dt\"','"\"server\":\"$ser_nm\",\"error\":\"$error_msg\""}

- Sai Kumar(Bigger the problem bigger the smile when it is resolved)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use [logstash and write a GROK](https://logz.io/blog/logstash-grok/) matching the message. If you don't want to use logstash, there are [ingest pipelines in elastisearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) for exactly this kind of case.

Please have a look on this detailed blog post: https://towardsdatascience.com/from-scratch-to-search-playing-with-your-data-elasticsearch-ingest-pipelines-6d054bf5d866

And for the case, you are not familiar with GROK, here is a pattern matching your specs:

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date}%{SPACE}%{IPORHOST:server}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:error}
```

EDIT:
Why to not solve this via shell? Because the logs needs to be processed continously as tgey are coming in.

Comment: As per client requirement we do not use logstash. We are using fluentd.

Comment: K, then go for the ingest pipeline :D

Comment: How can we do it via Shell??

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: None created a sample json log and created visualizations to present them.

Comment: but we do need a method to convert them to json.